# Potential Variable Clash in Excel Name Manager?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I was using name manager for automatic updating in charts. However it seemed I could not use the name `Cow_Days`. I tried changing everything and nothing work except changing the name to `HillC_Days`.

Does this mean there is a clash with a variable name in Excel? Why was it only the name that did not let it work? If it is relevant the formula for the `Cow_Days/HillC_Days` name is:

```
=INDEX(Cowies_Hill!$D:$D,MATCH(Cowies_Hill!$AM$4,Cowies_Hill!$D:$D,0)):INDEX(Cowies_Hill!$D:$D,MATCH(Cowies_Hill!$AM$5,Cowies_Hill!$D:$D,0))
```

Most bizarre and extremely frustrating.

Comment: A) Did you have a worksheet, chart or any other object named *Cow_Days*? B) What does that sample formula have to do with your question?

Comment: No but the Worksheet was called Cowies_Hill. The sample formula is for the name Cow_Days in name manager.

Comment: In fact any name that I tried that starts with 'Cow...' does not work. I am now using HillC as the variable name.

Comment: I found that all of the names that I use cannot start with the same first three letters as the worksheet names.

Comment: Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 2010---Version 14.0.4760.1000 (32-bit)